# How to use max(timestamp) with summarize when using other aggregated columns (count()) in kusto (kql)?

Tags: max, azure-log-analytics, kql

I am trying to write a query in kusto (kql), where I would check which users how many times accessed what projects.

```
pageViews
| extend projectId = extract(@"/projects/([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-zA-Z]{21,22})", 1, url)
| where url matches regex @'/projects/([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-zA-Z]{21,22})' 
and timestamp > ago(90d)
and isnotempty(user_Id)
| project timestamp, user_AccountId, user_Id, url, projectId
| summarize projectRequests = count() by  user_Id, projectId
```

I need to extend this functionality by when was the last access

I tried:

```
pageViews
| extend projectId = extract(@"/projects/([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-zA-Z]{21,22})", 1, url)
| where url matches regex @'/projects/([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-zA-Z]{21,22})' 
and timestamp > ago(90d)
and isnotempty(user_Id)
| project timestamp, user_AccountId, user_Id, url, projectId
| summarize projectRequests = count() by  user_Id, projectId, LastEdit = max(timestamp)
```

but it gave me

> Function 'max' cannot be invoked in current context

**How could I extend this query to include when was the project accessed last?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace:

`| summarize projectRequests = count() by  user_Id, projectId, LastEdit = max(timestamp)`

with

`| summarize projectRequests = count(), LastEdit = max(timestamp) by user_Id, projectId`

Answer (score 0):

I had to flip around `LastEdit = max(timestamp)` and `ProjectRequests = count() by  user_Id, projectId`.

like:

```
pageViews
| extend projectId = extract(@"/projects/([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-zA-Z]{21,22})", 1, url)
| where url matches regex @'/projects/([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-zA-Z]{21,22})' 
and timestamp > ago(90d)
and isnotempty(user_Id)
| project timestamp, user_AccountId, user_Id, url, projectId
| summarize LastEdit = max(timestamp), ProjectRequests = count() by  user_Id, projectId
```